# How to make a DataTemplate respond to a double-click in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, graphviz

I have a `DataTemplate` I've defined in my XAML which I'm using to display graph nodes in conjuction with [GraphViz4Net](https://github.com/tomap/Graphviz4Net). I'd like to be able to take an action when a user double-clicks a vertex. Using their example code, I can change the style of a vertex when it's moused-over:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DocumentPart}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="White">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="#BBBBBB" 
                                                        Opacity="0.3" Direction="315"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How do I handle double-click events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `MouseBinding`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DocumentPart}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="White">
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                          Command="{Binding YourBindableCommand}"
        </Border.InputBindings>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="#BBBBBB" 
                                                Opacity="0.3" Direction="315"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. You wouldn't believe all the other convoluted solutions I've found on blogs, etc.--many used code-behind and some even used timers to detect a double-click.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `EventSetter` inside the `Style`

`<EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DoubleClick_Handler"/>`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the Code-behind? I.e. using ICommand?

Comment: Also, I can't just add an `EventSetter` with that event to the style without specifying a `TargetType`. To do that, I need to wrap the `Border` in a `ContentControl`.